# Crash in react-native-Uuid-generator when using library in expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, uuid

I want to generate a uuid in ReactNative app built with expo cli.. when I install `UUIDGenerator` from `React-native-uuid-generator`, I get `undefined is not an object(evaluating ‘RNUUIDGenerator.getRandomUUID’..)`

Tried two dif libraries, `react-native-uuid`, and `React-native-uuid-generator`, same problem, think it might have to do with expo not liking the link command.

```
UUIDGenerator.getRandomUUID().then(uuid => console.log(uuid));
```

Expecting new uuid to be printed, actually getting error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`react-native-uuid` works with expo.

```
npm install react-native-uuid --save

import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';
```

then generatte uuid like

```
const uuid = uuid.v1();
```

Comment: Does not work with ejected expo due to missing `stream` dependency

Comment: We recently released an updated version using TypeScript – https://github.com/eugenehp/react-native-uuid